# Super class retrieve attributes from a class that inherits it

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to do in python a class that takes attributes of the class that inherits from it? Something more or less like the Django models class Meta. If possible sample code

Comment: Django Meta classes do not inherit from anything, neither do they have subclasses, so it's not clear what you are asking. You need to show an example of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't override an attribute of the parent class, the default value would be the one from the parent class, for example:

```
class ParentClass:
    some_attribute = 'Some value'

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    pass
```

Now if you access the attribute in a ChildClass instance:

```
child = ChildClass()
print(child.some_attribute)  # will print 'Some value'
```

The same applies for Model Classes, if you don't override the Meta class you would get the values from the Parent Model Class